# Would " S = { x | x belongs to S} " count as a syntactically correct sentence in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, notation, predicate-logic

Are there in ( standard) set theory syntactic rules preventing from writing this :

S = { x | x belongs to S}?

Sure, this sentence does not provide any information; it is semantically vacuous. But is it also syntactically incorrect?

Comment: Do you mean $$S=\{x:x\in S\}?$$

Comment: Yes, I meant "membership relation".

Comment: Whatever your $S$ is, I believe it is very much equal to the set on the right hand side. I don't much about syntax, but as long as this is not a definition of $S$ but a statement, it is correct and true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider a formal presentation of set theory.

We can consider e.g. [$\mathsf {ZF}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html#AxiSetThe) :

> it is an axiom system formulated in first-order logic with equality and with only one binary relation symbol $\in$ for membership.

This means that there are only two types of *atomic* formulas : $A=B$ and $A \in B$.

It is typical to introduce *abbreviations* (i.e. defined symbols) based on the "braces".

We can start defining : $\{ A,B \} = w \leftrightarrow \forall z (z \in w \leftrightarrow (z=A \lor z=B))$, denoting the *pair*, whose existence is licensed by the [Pair axiom](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/index.html#AxiZFC).

From it, we derive $\{ A \}$ for the *singleton*.

More generally, we define a *definition schema* for the [set-builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate) operator (a syntactical object mapping a *formula* to a *term*) :

> > $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}=y \leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))$ and $y$ is a *set*.

The previous example (the *pair* symbol) is an instance of this schema.

---

As said above, $x \in S$ is an atomic formula; thus we can use it as the formula $\varphi(x)$ in the definition schema above.

Obviously, if $S$ is a set :

> $S = \{ x \mid x \in S \}$.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically is correct. Is like saying that 2=2 but outside of the context describing what “2” means. There is no purpose at describing a set S as the collection of its own elements because that is the general definition of a set and not a description of a particular set S.

If I were to investigate the properties of the set S or of an element x, I would start with:

$x: x\epsilon S$

This sentence describes x as an element of a set S by relating the symbol x to the sentence that x belongs to S.